# conversion error between JSON for Chinese characters

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, json

I have a Chinese string "普派" that I want to transmit from client to web server using HTTP POST request. At the client side, I use the following jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/detect/word',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify('普派'),
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

At the server side, I use python 3.3:

```
class DictRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        post_data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
        post_var = json.loads(post_data.decode())
```

But the result (`post_var`) is messy. The variable `post_data` of type `bytes` is:
b'"\xc3\xa6\xe2\x84\xa2\xc2\xae\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb4\xc2\xbe"', but to correctly convert, it should be b'"\u666e\u6d3e"' (obtained by `json.dumps("普派").encode()`). Could you please help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `JSON.stringify('普派')` depends on the encoding of your source file. Remember, what's really between that quotes is just a bunch of bytes, it's just your editor (or browser) that displays it as '普派'.
If the browser correctly detects your source encoding, then it shouldn't relly matter, but if it doesn't, then you'll end up with garbage.
So make sure to supply the correct file encoding (which should preferably be utf-8).

To be independent of such browser dependent interpretations try changing it to `JSON.stringify("\u666e\u6d3e")`.

The json standard doesn't mandate that unicode characters must be replaced with teir unicode escape sequence on encoding.
It just defines that the encoding [should be unicode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-3), and allows for 'any unicode character' within json strings, so the result of `JSON.stringify` isn't wrong if it encodes the given charactes as utf-8.
Either one should be fine, so what you should see on your server side should probably be `b'"\xe6\x99\xae\xe6\xb4\xbe"'`.

Comment: I saveas the html file as utf-8 encoding and check it with file -bi command, I also add "contentType:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"," in the $.ajax function call, but the same problem persists -- I always got incorrect \xc3\xa6\xe2\x84\xa2\xc2\xae\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb4\xc2\xbe. I can't use JSON.stringify("\u666e\u6d3e") because jquery doesn't know how to convert 普派 to \u666e\u6d3e (I got it using python) or \xe6\x99\xae\xe6\xb4\xbe. The thing is, what the encoding JSON.stringify is using to convert 普派 to \xc3\xa6\xe2\x84\xa2\xc2\xae\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb4\xc2\xbe? how to check it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.