# How to make djangorestframework support Chinese?

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework

On my android device, I am making a simple RESTful POST request to my server in English ("hello world").  This works, and then a simple GET request can return "hello world" as a response.
But when I post in Chinese, the server receives ???? and the GET request returns ???
I am entering Chinese text on the Android device.

What do I need to do to enable djangorestframework to work with Chinese?

Thank you!

In django settings.py I've already enabled:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LOCALES = (
    ('en', u'English'),
    ('zh-tw', u'Mandarin (Taiwan)'),
    ('zh-cn', u'Mandarin (China)'),
)
```

Comment: What version of django? (zh-cn is removed in 1.9). Please show a small piece of example code of the request you are creating also

Comment: I am on Django 1.8; I've also tried zh-hans and zh-hant , neither of which work.  I do believe it is the sending of chinese characters to the server that is the problem. writing on the device and saving my text in sqlite on the device (no server interaction), the chinese is fine.  restframework is sending ??? to the server, that's what I believe I have the restframework settings wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The translation will only work for the browsable API and might for error response messages.

You probably need to double check your client side encoding. [conversion error between JSON for Chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341986/conversion-error-between-json-for-chinese-characters) has a good explanation about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jsonEntity.toString()),"UTF-8")
```

Many are using asynchttpclient for android to make network requests.  So anytime you're posting something to the server, you'll use a StringEntity.  So just make sure to specify the encoding as above. Then things work fine. Don't need to do anything to Django settings or Djangorestframework.